# python - expected an indented block while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, break

so this is my code, creating a rock paper scissors game.
i dont have anything else to say but the 
system here says i need more details because there is too much code so im randomly typing. thank you though.

```
options=["rock","paper","scissors"]

your_wins=0
my_wins=0

while input!="exit":
    turn = input("Please choose rock,paper or scissors:")
    print("you chose:" + turn)

    import random
    my_choice = random.choice(options)
    print("I chose:" + my_choice)

    if my_choice=="rock" and turn=="rock":
        print("its a tie!")

    if my_choice=="paper" and turn=="rock":
        print("you lose!")

    if my_choice=="scissors" and turn=="rock":
        print("you win!")

    if my_choice=="paper" and turn=="paper":
        print("its a tie!")

    if my_choice=="scissors" and turn=="paper":
        print("you lose!")

    if my_choice=="rock" and turn=="paper":
        print("you win!")

    if my_choice=="paper" and turn=="scissors":
        print("you win!")

    if my_choice=="scissors" and turn=="scissors":
        print("its a tie!")

    if my_choice=="rock" and turn=="scissors":
        print("you lose!")
    if "you lose":
        my_wins+=1
    else:
        your_wins+=1

if input=="exit":
break
```

why do i get this error? Its on the break.
I tried different things, but it just wont work..
thank you for the help!!

Comment: The only error I see is the `break` statement not indented under the `if` at the very end, but that entire `if` statement should also be intended to make it part of the `while` loop.

Comment: Whatever error you are getting should include the line where the error occurs; you should always post the *exact* error message you receive.

Answer (score 0):

include the "if input == 'exit'" in the while loop and then indent the 'break' inside it